# XSLT transform failing to template match

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to perform a find and replace on an XML using an XSLT transform. I thought I could template match the element using XPath, select the attribute I want to transform (Value) then change it using xsl:value-of select="". I have a similar working example which is what I used to construct this attempt. The find and replace is from this example and I'm confident that it is not causing the transform to fail.

XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Site xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Description="Basic Cadastre layers with Imagery layers " DisplayName="bwi" DisplayTimeZoneID="Australia/Canberra" ID="bwi" SignInEnabled="false" SignOutEnabled="false" SplashScreenUrl="{RestVirtualDirectoryUrl}/Images/Icons/SplashScreen_bwi.png" TimeZoneID="Australia/Canberra" Version="4.6.2">
      <Workflows>
        <Workflow DisplayName="AddPointXY" ID="AddPointXY" RunOnStartup="false" Uri="{RootUri}/Resources/Workflows/AddPointXY.xaml">
          <Properties>
            <Property Name="GeometryServer" Value="http://dev-data.actmapi.act.gov.au/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/Geometry/GeometryServer" />
          </Properties>
        </Workflow>
      </Workflows>
    </Site>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:regexp="http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"
  extension-element-prefixes="regexp">

  <!-- Copy the document to work with -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match='//Workflows/Workflow/Properties/Property'>
            <xsl:attribute name="Value">
                <xsl:value-of select="regexp:replace(string(.),'(dev-data.actmapi.act.gov.au)','gi','test-data.actmapi.act.gov.au')" />
            </xsl:attribute>    
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Where is the function 'regexp:replace()'?

Comment: While posting the question please specify the desired output as well, you can do very easy in XSLT 2.0 by replace() function.

Comment: Try changing your match to `match="Property/@Value"`

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that worked! I can't seem to upvote your comment but I want to say thanks anyway.

Comment: @AmrendraKumar While the output XML would usually be required, it is quite easy to see the intent of the question without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSLT 2.0 :

**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <!-- Copy the document to work with -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//Workflows/Workflow/Properties/Property/@Value">
        <xsl:attribute name="Value">
            <xsl:value-of select="replace(.,'dev-data.actmapi.act.gov.au','test-data.actmapi.act.gov.au')" />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**